# Can I use AF_ALG to compress?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kernel, compression

I played around with [these examples](https://github.com/nibrunie/af_alg-examples/tree/master/examples) to 1. SHA1 a string 2. hmac(sha1) a string (which isn't shown as an example) and 3) encrypt

`cat /proc/crypto` shows zstd. However I can't seen to figure out how to use it. I tried the types listed in /proc/crypto and several variations. bind always fails. Is zstd or any compression supported? I'm specifically looking for a way to use them through the kernel I know I could always get the source and compile it or link to a shared object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As of v6.5.9, Search `af_alg_register_type` in linux kernel code, it seems that only "aead", "hash", "rng" and "skcipher" are registered. So compression type will not be found in `bind()`.

I guess you can use zstd alg if you write a kernel module.